# What to do with new answer to old questions when they don't add anything new?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/201294/34147) was just posted to an 18-month-old question. Of course, there's nothing inherently wrong with a new answer to an old question, but it adds absolutely nothing to the already accepted answer except the answerer's own backstory (which isn't much different than in the OP).

I get that it doesn't actively *hurt* the site for this answer to be there, but it seems "wrong". Is there a suggested course of action beyond posting a comment such as the one I made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mods have a few actions to pick from. In this case we can do nothing, delete it, or convert it to a comment. If it's a "me too" style answer, I tend to delete after commenting with:

> Deleting because this is a "me too" answer. Once you have sufficient
> [reputation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)
> you’ll be able to [vote up questions and answers you found
> helpful](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

That hopefully directs users to work on getting a small bit a reputation so they can vote on the site.

---

In this particular case, I'm inclined to convert the answer into a comment on the related answer since it provides a bit of additional context.

Since "it's kinda an answer but already covered by other answers and might be useful converted to a comment" isn't one of the precanned mod flags, feel free to flag with a custom reason and mods can have a look.

---

Disclaimers: this is my own personal view, other mods may have different opinions, and as always I'm curious when the community disagrees so we can adjust to maintain the site as they prefer.

Comment: "feel free to flag with a custom reason and mods can have a look." Unless I see loud, dissenting opinions in the next day or so, I'll do just that. Thanks.