# Over the last few days, I've been seeing very old posts with 1,000s or more views suddenly show up on recent questions. Why? Bug in SE?

Tags: bug

Recently I've seen questions that are quite old (1-5 years) suddenly appear on DIY recent questions. I don't seem to be able to close them as "late answers" , maybe I don't yet have enough reputation points to do that, but that's not the issue. The issue why did this suddenly start happening?

Here is one example posted earlier by FreeMan, apparently he's experiencing the same thing.   I'll edit and post more as I run across them.

[What to do with new answer to old questions when they don't add anything new?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/what-to-do-with-new-answer-to-old-questions-when-they-dont-add-anything-new)

Just ran across another one: [Need help identifying the manufacturer of a frost free anti-siphon faucet.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141060/need-help-identifying-the-manufacturer-of-a-frost-free-anti-siphon-faucet)

Comment: Please [edit] some examples into your post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, meant to post this to the SE META site. My mistake. When I run across another example I'll update my post there.   I'll delete this after a bit. .

Comment: If you do post on [meta.se], it'll probably just get migrated back here.

Comment: OK, thanks, still learning about the protocols at SE  +

Comment: To be clear, are you maybe asking about the community bump? https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/949/why-does-community-regularly-bring-very-old-topics-back-up-to-the-top or https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/why-so-many-community-bumps-can-should-it-be-changed

Comment: A whole new world of deleted content will open up to you once you hit 10k reputation. You're very clsoe!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you provided had a recently added answer that didn't wasn't actually an answer. Any new answer, or edit to an existing question or answer, will bump the question if you sort by active posts. People do that from time to time, particularly new users that don't read how the site works.

Since the answer didn't meet our guidelines, I've deleted it after it was flagged by other users on the site. If you don't have enough reputation to view deleted answers, it may appear that a question was bumped for no reason at all.

Additionally, it's possible for the Community user to bump old posts. This is automated from SE, and is done on questions where the question itself is upvoted, but none of the answers are upvoted, in an attempt to get more attention to the question, possibly a better answer, votes on existing answers, or even down votes on the question if it need improvement.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if Community bumps a post [it will show in the post timeline](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/221349/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)